# Retaliatory downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, moderation

I just posted an answer to an old question that needed an up to date answer. I also downvoted the accepted answer and left a comment explaining it was outdated. Within minutes though my new answer was downvoted without an explanation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56155547/2444959

Normally I would’t care about this. But this question kind of needs an up to date answer. Prior to answering it I spent quite some time researching the topic so I could solve a similar issue my self, time that would have been saved if this answer was already there.

I’m wondering if this can be fixed because it would be bad if a user with a similar issue to mine would stumble upon my answer, see it with a negative score, and then given the impression that this answer is not a good solution. Then spend unnecessary time researching further. Worse they might leave with the impression that an up to date solution is sub-optimal.

Comment: I personally don't see any good reason to downvote answer that explicitly says which scope it applies to - the fact you have broader answer does not mean existing one becomes wrong. And I don't see reasons why answer with *zero* explanation deserves more than downvotes - you should at least address why you think it is ok to provide no explanation as part of this post.

Comment: By answering the question, you bumped it to the front page. Anyone visiting the front page (or any other page it may have been bumped to the top of) at that point in time could have been the person who cast said downvote.

Comment: @KevinB correct. I have no evidence that the downvote was retaliatory. Perhaps I should have worded the title differently. I do find it suspect that the answer is not wrong, it provides the information the question was asking (missing in the accepted answer). So I don’t really know why it was downvoted. My only remaining theory is retaliation, which I cannot get any evidence for.

Comment: The [user who you downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/591776/cereallarceny) has [not been online for the last four and a half days](https://i.imgur.com/FfvcdsZ.png). That was about four days at the time of you posting your answer. I very highly doubt they "retaliated" to your downvote unless the implication is that it was through a sock puppet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes wrong claims and has sparked too toxic debate. I'm embarrassed that I raised this issue. I should have never posted it.

Comment: *" I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes wrong claims and has sparked too toxic debate. I'm embarrassed that I raised this issue. I should have never posted it."* - jebus, take it easy :/ No harm done and there is no toxic debate.

Comment: @Gimby Its toxic because I accused someone of things they didn’t do, and whoever’s arguing against me go downvote my answer because of that (5 downvotes despite being the best answer ). It is a caricature of a political debate where the issue being debated is secondary to being right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That you received one downvote on one answer is not compelling evidence of voting fraud.  It's entirely plausible that whomever downvoted the post honestly feels it's not a useful answer to the question.  They're not at all required to justify their vote to you either.

If other readers of the answer feel it's useful, you may attract additional upvotes.  If other readers feel it's not useful, it may continue to attract more downvotes.  Such is the nature of community voted content.  Not everyone will always agree with you on the usefulness of posts.

Comment: Yes!... But it is still perfectly good reason for retaliatory downvote :)

Comment: Fair enough. Just to be clear, I’m not accusing anyone of voting fraud, just an unfortunate retaliatory downvote. Unfortunate because a non-seasoned web developer might see a single downvote and learn the wrong lesson.

Comment: @RúnarBerg I don't think there is anything retaliatory in downvoting a post with zero explanations. If you feel otherwise make sure to clarify in your post. Providing comment (or just any vote) is a way to attract attention from author to given Q&A - it is always good idea to make sure your own contributions can handle that additional attention (including meta effect you are triggering now)

Comment: @RúnarBerg You're accusing someone of voting for something other than the usefulness of the post, which is voting fraud.  And it's an accusation that you don't have adequate evidence to actually make.  You think it's a good answer and it's a shame others might think it's not good because of a downvote, whereas the voter presumably thinks it's not a good answer and it's a good thing users not qualified to evaluate it will be wary of it, and cast their vote accordingly.

Comment: @Servy Sorry for making an accusation. That was not my intention. I figured the question mark in the title made it clear that I’m only speculating. Apparently I was wrong. I’ll try to be more careful in my future posts on meta.